# Remove orphaned users

Tags: sql-server

Lately my server crashed and I had to backup the database and restore it to a new windows installation.

This database had some Users. I'm trying to delete them because they are now orphaned but I keep getting this message **"The database principal owns a service in the database, and cannot be dropped."**

[I've tried several attempts including this article](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1578941/Removing-Orphan-Users-from-All-databases-on-SQL-Server.htm).

I've used

```
exec sp_revokedbaccess 'UserToDelete'
```

No luck, still getting the same error. Please help me if you encountered this before.

Comment: Try too see what happen on profiler sql when you executing the delete query

Comment: You can be take look at : http://developmenttips.blogspot.com/2012/07/drop-orphaned-user-who-holds-sql-server.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you very much Pascal!!! this article solved my problem !!

Comment: A i ´m glad to help you . :) have a god day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Article to resolve :

http://developmenttips.blogspot.com/2012/07/drop-orphaned-user-who-holds-sql-server.html?m=1

I think this worked.

Comment: Yes it definitely did!!